# Why methods valueValidate and valueSubmit don't execute?

Tags: views, 8, plugins

I'm trying to create a views filter containing an exposed form.

The filter class is inherited from FilterPluginBase. In principle, the filter almost works, but I have run into a strange problem.

I want to modify some data upon submitting the exposed form and use for it a method valueSubmit.

Here is the code of my filter class.

```
/**
 * Class PalomGeoFilter
 * @package Drupal\field_elements\Plugin\views\filter
 *
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("palom_views_geo_filter")
 */
class PalomGeoFilter extends FilterPluginBase {

  public function valueForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    parent::valueForm($form, $form_state);

    if ($form_state->get('exposed')){

      $form['country_id'] = [
        '#empty_option' => t('Select a country'),
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Country'),
        '#options' => PalomGeo::getCountryList(),
        '#default_value' => 2,
      ];

      $form['region_id'] = [
        '#empty_option' => t('All the regions'),
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Region'),
        '#options' => PalomGeo::getRegionList(2),
      ];

      $form['value'] = [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#default_value' => '2_0',
      ];
    }
  }

  protected function valueSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
//    parent::valueSubmit($form, $form_state); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

    $form_state->setValue(['value'], '49_0');
  }

  public function query()
  {
///
  }

}
```

But somehow this method doesn't want to be executed. I tried to make a breakpoint inside that method for XDebug or output a message using drupal_set_message, but it isn't executed.

What can be a reason for it?

Has anybody encountered it?

Comment: What value do you get for `$this->isAGroup()`?

Comment: Try moving the `parent::valueForm($form, $form_state);` line after `if ($form_state->get('exposed')){ ...... }` closing bracket.

Comment: $this->isAGroup() returns false;

Comment: I tried moving the line parent::valueForm($form, $form_state); after the if-block, but after it the hidden field "value" became undefined.

Comment: As I found out, the method valueSubmit is executed not when I use an exposed form on the view, but it is executed on the view edit page upon editing the filter settings form. Which method should I use to manipulate data, inputted in the exposed form ?